# What's the correct Active record association for multiple has many through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi guys I have an interesting has many through problem with `Rails4`. I have `Users`, `Libraries` and `Documents`. Each `User` can have access to one or more `libraries` and each `document` can exist in one or more `libraries`. There can be over a million documents.  So a User has multiple libraries and a library has multiple documents. I have a user_libraries table and a slide_libraries table, to link the different models. I am trying to efficiently get all the available documents for a user.

Right now I can get all libraries for a user and all slides for a library, but getting all slides for a user has proved elusive. Thanks in advance.

Update..

Apologies for lack lack of clarity in the problem. This issue exists in that a document can exist in multiple libraries, so it has a join table also.

A user has many libraries. So the User_Library table (join table) has a user id and a library_type_id

The Document_Library table has a document_id and a library_type_id

I can currently use User.libraries.first.documents and get all the documents on a per library basis.

The idea is to get all the documents for all the libraries that a user has access to.

I think the issue is that we have multiple join tables, otherwise I could just us a has many through...

Comment: It worked for me :D what is your problem exactly?

Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: From what I can understand all you need is -> `Users has_many Libraries ` and `Libraries  has_many Documnets`. Then you can easily access using `user.libraries` & `user.library.documents`.

Comment: Can you please update your question by posting your models with their associations?